# Import C++ dll in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a C++ dll for monitoring printers (using FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification). I am making C# Wrapper for it:

```
private static class NativeMethods {
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}

    public string LibPath;
    private IntPtr LibPtr;
    private GBtMX GBtMain;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void GBtMX();

    public GhostBuster() {
        LibPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\GhostBusterC.dll";
    }

    public string Init() {
        if (!File.Exists(LibPath))
            return "Incorrect path " + LibPath;
        LibPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(LibPath);
        if (LibPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            return "Couldn't import library. Error(GetLastWin32Error): " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString();

        IntPtr GBtMainPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(LibPtr, "tmain");
        if (GBtMainPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            return "No access to GhostBuster.tmain.  Error (GetLastWin32Error): " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString();
        GBtMain = (GBtMX)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GBtMainPtr, typeof(GBtMX));            
        return "";
```

It returns "No access to GhostBuster.tmain. Error (GetLastWin32Error): 0".
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify `SetLastError` in your p/invoke, so that's why `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` is failing to return anything useful. The p/invoke should be

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(
    IntPtr hModule, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    string lpProcName
);
```

Note also that it makes sense to be explicit about the marshaling of the procedure name. That is always an ANSI string, reflecting the PE format.

When you make this change I expect that the error will be `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND` indicating that the DLL does not export anything with the name that you passed to `GetProcAddress`.

Check that you spelled the function name correctly. Did you get the letter case right? Is there any decoration or mangling applied when the DLL is built? Use a tool like `dumpbin` or Dependency Walker to check the names of the DLL's exports.

Comment: Thatis because I made the same mistake as you, the same mistake I described in my first sentence! I've edited it now. It pays to read the text as well as the code ....